# Moderator Revision Redaction Approval display issue

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

I saw a small display bug today in the new admin flag dashboard.

When a Moderator Revision Redaction Approval flag is open, the content is full screen and not inside the correct table layout.

I tested with Firefox and Chrome.

See an example below; it's heavily redacted for obvious reason, but where you see black lines text was there, and at the right, my picture doesn't show it, but a code block vertical scrollbar is misplaced there too.

[image: Screenshot of Moderator Revision Redaction Approval flag dashboard]

Comment: I see the same problem, using Chrome.  It's so hard to read I can't even risk confirming the redaction...

Comment: @YaakovEllis looks fixed now.